# Add something to a textfield after button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am trying to, when the button a is clicked, add the letter to the textfield. However, I cant seem to figure out why it isn't working. I got the code for it from here on stack exchange. Any help is as always appreciated.

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style>
    tab1 { padding-left: 8em; }
    tab2 { padding-left: 12em; }
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js'></script>

</head>
<body style="background-color:powderblue;">

<tab2><input id="bar a" style="height:20px;width:120px" type="button" value="a" onlick=buttonPress('a')/><br><br>


<tab1><input id ="stringInput" type="text" value=""/><br>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


    var added;
function buttonPress(added)
{
    document.getElementById("bar a").addEventListener('click', function () {
    var text = document.getElementById('stringInput');
    text.text = (text.text + added);
});
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: jquery tag is useless for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to attach `event` as you are already calling function `onclick`.

Aslo you need `value` property of `textbox` not `text`

```
function buttonPress(added)
{
  var text = document.getElementById('stringInput');
  text.value= (text.value + added);

}
```

Also your html for `button` in invalid.It should be

```
<input id="bar a" style="height:20px;width:120px" type="button" value="a"  onclick="buttonPress('a')" />
```

Comment: also, you have to change **onlick** to **onclick** , and put the method between quotes

Comment: @CelsoAgra yes just saw that and updated answer thanks

Comment: You had written `onlick` which should be `onclick` aslo `buttonPress('a)` should be enclosed in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style>
    tab1 { padding-left: 8em; }
    tab2 { padding-left: 12em; }
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js'></script>

</head>
<body style="background-color:powderblue;">
<input type="text" value="" id="test1">
<input id ="test2" type="text" value="ram"/><br>
<input type="button" onclick="addInput()"/ value="click">

<span id="responce"></span>
<script>
function addInput()
{
     var test1_value= document.getElementById('test1').value;
     var test2_value= document.getElementById('test2').value;
     document.getElementById('test2').value=''+test2_value+''+test1_value;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues in your code. Not sure if it is a typo in your code.

For example   `onlick=buttonPress('a')` . It should be `onclick` and the  handler function should be quotes. Refer to the below html.

There is also no need of adding `addEventListener` inside function. You have already added the listener in the html code. If you add the listener inside the function, then on first click it will again try to add the the event.

Refer to the below js. Hope this will be useful

```
var added = " New Text";
function buttonPress(added) {
  var text = document.getElementById('stringInput');
  text.value = (text.value + added);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="bar" style="height:20px;width:120px" type="button" value="a" onclick='buttonPress("a")' />
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/kuon64pp/7/)

Answer (score -1):

1. your onclick is mispelled as onlick. This will be read as a custom attribute.
2. put the buttonPress('a') inside "". It will become onclick="buttonPress('a')". It prompts an error when it's not inside "".
3. since you are using an input for the component with id "stringInput", text property does not work so you have to use the value property instead.